# Finding roads in one particular province of The Netherlands using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, netherlands

I have two shapefiles that I want to use to see all the roads in one particular province of The Netherlands.

So I have one layer with all the roads in The Netherlands and one layer with the boundaries of every province.

How can I 'select' or 'show' the roads in this one particular province? The attributes of the roads file doesn't contain data saying in wich province it is.

I am a beginner in using QGIS 2.0.1.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an [intersection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_%28set_theory%29) of the features. You can find it here:
`Vector > Geoprocessing Tools > Intersect...`

[image]

As the input layer you use the roads. As intersect layer you use the provinces of the netherlands. Either you can make a filter for the province you need or you select the province and check the Use only selected features box. Then you can process a new shapefile with only the streets of the area.

If you want that the roads are clipped at the province boundaries, you can use the clip function of qgis: `Vector > Geoprocessing Tools > Clip...`.

Comment: I think this is what I was looking for, but the resulting shapefile appears to be empty. I tried this with leaving the checkboxes clear: no result. Then I selected one province, checkboxed 'Use only selected features'. Processing took 3 minutes and it created the new layer but it's empty.

Comment: Are the layer in the same coordinate reference system? The systems are in `left click in the layers menue > Properties > General > Coordinate Reference System` If you open the generated file in another project it is still empty?

Comment: They aren't. But when I change the CRS in that menu, the shapefile/polygons disappear.

Comment: Try to save the both files in the same crs. Here is the QGIS manual on how to do this:  http://docs.qgis.org/2.2/de/docs/training_manual/vector_analysis/reproject_transform.html#moderate-fa-saving-a-dataset-to-another-crs This should transform the coordinates to the other crs and the position should be the same.